# celery supervisor returns "no such file or directory" error

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I'm using supervisor to daemonize my django project. If I don't start celery from supervisor but start from shell `(celery -A proj worker --app=proj.celery:app --loglevel=INFO)` everything works fine. When I daemonize the celery program, task logs `No such file or directory` and finishes immediately.

There isn't any other problem, workers are alive, `supervisorctl` status celery is `RUNNING` etc. Whats the problem?

My `celery_err.log` file content:

```
[2018-04-08 15:24:01,121: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2018-04-08 15:24:01,131: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-04-08 15:24:02,135: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-04-08 15:24:02,143: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/ali/Desktop/proj/projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2018-04-08 15:24:02,143: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@debian ready.
[2018-04-08 15:24:32,789: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task_proj[441f7326-c847-4a29-a65d-543b8794e7a3]
[2018-04-08 15:24:32,797: INFO/Worker-2] task_proj[441f7326-c847-4a29-a65d-543b8794e7a3]: Sent scan request successfully
[2018-04-08 15:24:32,831: WARNING/Worker-2] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[2018-04-08 15:24:32,843: WARNING/Worker-2] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

​
my `supervisord.conf` file content:

```
[program:proj]
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ,PATH="/var/www/proj/projenv/bin", PROJ_ENV_FILE="/var/www/proj/proj.env",VIRTUAL_ENV="/var/www/proj/projenv",PYTHONPATH="/var/www/proj/projenv/lib/python:/var/www/proj/projenv/lib/python/site-packages"
command = /var/www/proj/bin/gunicorn_start                           
user = root                                                                 
redirect_stderr = true                                                     
stdout_logfile=/var/www/proj/logs/django.log
stderr_logfile=/var/www/proj/logs/django_err.log
​
[program:redis]
command = /etc/redis-4.0.2/src/redis-server
​
​
[program:celery]
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ,PATH="/var/www/proj/projenv/bin", PROJ_ENV_FILE="/var/www/proj/proj.env",VIRTUAL_ENV="/var/www/proj/projenv",PYTHONPATH="/var/www/proj/projenv/lib/python:/var/www/proj/projenv/lib/python/site-packages"
directory=/var/www/proj/proj
command = /var/www/proj/projenv/bin/celery -A proj worker --app=proj.celery:app --loglevel=INFO
user = root
redirect_stderr = true                                                       
stdout_logfile = /var/www/proj/logs/celery.log
stderr_logfile = /var/www/proj/logs/celery_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
```

Answer (score 0):

Celery program directory should be pointing to the root of the project and not to the base app. So instead of `directory=/var/www/proj/proj`, it should be `directory=/var/www/proj`.